# Why do my inputs on the page disappear after refreshing the page, but the inputs are saved in local storage in the console?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

link to my web application: https://malekmekdashi.github.io/work_day_scheduler/

link to my github repo: https://github.com/malekmekdashi/work_day_scheduler

I cannot seem to solve this issue that I'm having. My goal is that whenever I refresh the page after inputting some values in the text box, the values will remain on the page along with local storage. However, I am unable to do so. If someone can be so kind as to help me solve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Here is a little example of the code that I'm working with

HTML:

```html
<div class="row time-block" id="1">
   <div class="col-md-1 hour" id="1">9am</div>
   <textarea class="col-md-10 description" id="inputValue"></textarea>
   <button class="saveBtn col-md-1"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
$('.saveBtn').on('click', function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).siblings('.description').val();

    localStorage.setItem("inputValue", inputValue);
});

$('inputValue .description').val(localStorage.getItem('inputValue'));
```

Comment: It's because `$('inputValue .description')` returns an array. You'll need to grab a specific element, in order to update it's value

Comment: can you elaborate a little further please? what element do i need to grab? is it one that is already in my HTML?

Comment: As an example, try referencing the first element, with something like: `$('inputValue .description')[0].val(localStorage.getItem('inputValue'))`. But your best option is to give each element an ID, and store both the element ID / index and the value in local storage.

Comment: for instance, like this: `$('.saveBtn').on('click', function() {
   var inputValue = $(this).siblings('.description').val();
   var timeValue = $(this).parent('id');

   localStorage.setItem("inputValue", inputValue );
   localStorage.setItem("timeValue ", timeValue );
});

$('#inputValue.description').val(localStorage.getItem('inputValue'));
$('#timeValue .description').val(localStorage.getItem('timeValue '));`

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong in two ways.

1. Like in the comments already said: Your return will be an array. You have multiple ids `inputValue` with class `description`.
2. You want to select id `inputValue`, which means you need to use `#inputValue`. Also you need to combine them by leaving out the whitespace otherwise you search for childrens. Correct jQuery would be `$('#inputValue.description')`

Comment: ok i got something. I took your advice and used the correct jquery like you said, but whats happening now is that it's stored in all the spaces, not just one. Would i be correct in saying that I need to label the id's in my HTML differently, and apply multiple `$('#').val(localStorage.getItem(''))` for each ID in my HTML?

Comment: Yes! Otherwise you have no chance to differentiate if the text was saved in the first, second, third etc. field because they ALL have the same id and also ALL get's stored to the same variable in the `localStorage`.

Comment: will i also need to create new variables for my function for each new id that i created? along with `localStorage.setItem("");`?

Comment: You have 9 input fields, so you should have 9 different ids and save 9 different values in the `localStorage`. You may want to use some form of datastructure to save it.

Comment: little update: I am able to refresh the page and the values still remain, but the issue is that the inputs save in all the time-blocks and i dont know why. I have 9 different id's for the inputValues, but it doesnt make sense why the value saves under all the timeblocks

Comment: Your saveBtn function is still wrong because you don't get the right values. You set each variable to `$(this).siblings('.description').val()`. This will of course always return the same value.

Comment: youre right, but im still stuck on what i should use instead of `.description`. Shouldn't i be using the `id`?

Comment: Just use the same selectors to get and set the values. Get is the same as set just without parameter for `val()` like `$('#inputValue.description').val()`

Comment: so will my variable look like this: `var inputValue = $('#inputValue.description').val()'` and will i have to create multiple variables for each time-block, or can i use the same variable, but include multiple `setItem` and `getItem`